# How to connect sidebar in checkout progress?

Tags: spree

Solved with copying def seo_url to checkout helper.

Hello, Im trying to connect sidebar in checkout progress.
But I get this:

Showing c:/Projects/musthave/spree_theme_musthave/app/views/shared/_taxonomies.html.erb where line #6 raised:

undefined method `seo_url' for #<#:0x799d910>
Extracted source (around line #6):

```
3:   <ul class="navigation-list">  
4:    <li<%= ' class="current"' if @taxon && @taxon == taxonomy.root %>> <div class="sidebar_taxon"><%=taxonomy.name.singularize %></div></li>
5:    <% taxonomy.root.children.each do |taxon| %>
6:      <li<%= ' class="current"' if @taxon and ([@taxon] + @taxon.ancestors).include?(taxon) %>><%= link_to taxon.name, seo_url(taxon) %></li>
7:      
8:    <% end %>
9:  </ul>
```

`seo_url' is only mentioned in 'products_helper.rb':

```
def seo_url(taxon, product = nil)    
  return '/t/' + taxon.permalink if product.nil?
  warn "DEPRECATION: the /t/taxon-permalink/p/product-permalink urls are "+  
    "not used anymore. Use product_url instead. (called from #{caller[0]})"
  return product_url(product)
end
```

Cant figure out how to make it work. Searched everywhere, but couldnt find anything usefull.

Tried this one, but it didnt helped:

```
def get_taxonomies
  @taxonomies ||= Taxonomy.find(:all, :include => {:root => :children})
  @taxonomies.select { |t| !t.root.nil? }
end
```

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to display taxons or are you trying to display a sidebar?

if its just a sidebar you want you dont need to add your taxons in you can try

```
<% content_for :sidebar do %>
  <Add your sidebar content here...>
<% end %>
```

Thanks